# Show in groups: Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

Is it possible to enable "Show in Groups" option in Nautilus?
This option is available in Windows Explorer and in Dolphin.

Comment: What is "show in groups"? I'm not going to purchase a license of Windows and spend hours installing it in order to find out. Please try to provide details when you ask

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Similar items are grouped together based on the sorting method, so if it's alphabetic sorting, files beginning with `A` have a group, files starting with `B` have a group etc. That gets more complicated with other sorting methods like date. See this for a brief example of how it looks: http://www.ghacks.net/2008/08/11/windows-explorer-tip/

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad: Don't get so psyched about installing windows my friend :). If you need a first hand demo, install dolphin and activate "Show in Groups" by right clicking or from the menu bar.

Comment: The point is that you should just explain the feature, and not use deep references that require large amounts of work to understand. A screenshot, for instance, helps very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been suggested, first on [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1139445), then [BrainStorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/19877/) and finally on [GnomeLive](http://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Ideas/Unorganized/Sort%20by%20Type%20and%20Group%20by%20type%20like%20Windows%20Explorer).

BrainStorm says "This idea was marked as implemented the 29 January 12" but I honestly can't find any way of doing this in Nautilus 3.2.x so assume this was either incorrectly marked as implemented, it was implemented against the old 2.x version (and not carried forward) or I'm being an idiot and can't see how to turn it on.